# How can i create more than one infobubble in Here Maps

Tags: javascript, here-api

I need to place unlimited number of infobubbles for different occasions in the map. However whenever i place the second one, there is an error

```
IllegalArgument: Component instance with ID "InfoBubbles" already registered
```

Clearly, the problem is i need to assign each one a different id (i think the default id is "InfoBubbles" )  but i could not figure out how to do that.

```
var infoBubble1 = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();
var infoBubble2 = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();
map.components.add(infoBubble1);
map.components.add(infoBubble2); --> Error
```

I tried;

```
infoBubble1 .set("id", "xxx");
var infoBubble1 = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles({id = "xxx"}); -> not valid since infobubbles only have an empty constructor.
```

I use the version 2.5.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nomenclature problem - there are too many bubbles in the API. You are mixing up the `nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles` [component](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.html) (**plural**), which allows balloon texts to be created, with the `nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.Bubble` [interface](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.Bubble.html) itself (**singular**), which displays a balloon text on screen (actually adds a DOM element over the map).

There can only ever be one unique **component** with a unqiue `id` - hence the JavaScript library complains if you try to include it twice.

The way to open a new balloon text is to use `InfoBubbles.openBubble()` [method](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.html#topic-apiref__InfoBubbles-openBubble-method) which states:

> *This method creates a new info bubble, updates it with content and shows it on the map.*
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> content: `{String | DomElement}`   The content to be shown in the info bubble; it can be an HTML string, please note that
>   Flash content in the bubble overlap other elements in the document
>
> coordinate: `{nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate}`   An object containing the
>   geographic coordinates of the location, where the bubble's anchor is
>   to be placed.
>
> onUserClose: `{Function} [optional]`   A callback method which is
>   called when user closes the bubble (by clicking on close button) to be
>   placed.
>
> hideCloseButton: `{Boolean} [optional]` Hides close button if set to
>   true.

A working example can be found in the [Legacy API explorer](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/public/api-for-js/information-bubbles/extend-marker-to-infobubblemarker.html) - the important line of code is as follows:

```
var infoBubble = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();
map.components.add(infoBubble);
infoBubbles.openBubble(bubbleText1, coordinate1);
infoBubbles.openBubble(bubbleText2, coordinate2);
```

[image: Infobubbles]

So add your component once, and use the `openBubble()` method multiple times.

Comment: Good answer but what, if you have 2 maps on 1 page? The same error because the infobubbles are attached to both maps. Any way to bypass this?

Comment: I did that you recommend but it still doesn't work.
When I open second bubble, first disappears.